# Input field of type number is not showing default values (in angular)

Tags: html, angular, input, angular-template

I have the following code in stock-status.component.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stock-status',
  template:`
  <input type="number" value='0' min='0' required [(ngModel)]='updatedStockValue'/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" [style.background]='color' (click)='stockValueChanged()'>Change Stock Value</button>
    
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./stock-status.component.css']
})
```

As you can see in the image it is not showing the default value as 0 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO2OK.png)

And whenever I click the Button when no data is initialized , it shows NaN which is not what I want

Any Kind of Help and Guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModel` binding might have precedence here. You could ignore the `value` attribute and set `updatedStockValue` in it's definition.

Try the following

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stock-status',
  template:`
  <input type="number" min="0" required [(ngModel)]="updatedStockValue"/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" [style.background]="color" (click)="stockValueChanged()">Change Stock Value</button>
    
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./stock-status.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  updatedStockValue: number = 0;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a variable in the template with ng-init if you don't want to do it in the controller.

```
  <input type="number" min='0' required [(ngModel)]='updatedStockValue'
  ng-init="updatedStockValue=0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to work and has the same bugs as that of my code

@Michael's answer works great